# Iterate through object by dynamic property in handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I was trying to iterate through an object by using a dynamic property name it doesn't seem to be working:

```
{{#each orders["order" + name] }}
```

Not even this seems to be working

```
{{#each orders["orderDemo"] }}
```

But this does:

```
{{#each orders.orderDemo }}
```

Any solution to deal with dynamic property  names depending on other conditions or iterations?

In my case I have:

```
{{#each types}}
    {{#each orders[type] }}
        <table>....</table>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK *Handlebars* does not provide any build-in support for the dynamic properties, but you can register a simple "Helper Function" like this:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('orders', function(parent,child,options) {
  return parent["order"+child].map(options.fn).join``
});
```

and then use it as follows:

```
<ul>
  {{#orders orders name}}
      <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/orders}}
</ul>
```

If you are feeling *recursive*, you can even do:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('forEach', function(parent,expr,options) {
  return parent[Handlebars.compile(expr)(this)].map(options.fn).join``;
});

{{#forEach orders "order{{name}}" }}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
{{/forEach}}
```

but if you have a lot of data, this would be a performance hog.